# read( ) call hanging while reading a regular file

Tags: c++, linux, ace

I have a scenario where i open a file in a non blocking mode..

```
 currentFile1 = ACE_OS::open(completeFileName.c_str(), O_RDONLY, ACE_DEFAULT_OPEN_PERMS);

 bytesRead = ACE_OS::read(myCurrentFile, (char *)myIO_Buffer, 12);
```

During some strange scenario read hanged for a large amount of time. I read in forums that read generally does not hang in case of a regular file.

Is it possible that they get Blocked in case of regular files too ?

i would try with

```
O_NONBLOCK
```

in Open call. but is it really helpfull ??

Comment: You should probably do some io profiling (look at `iotop`) before coming to hasty conclusions. Also, this is C++, not C.

Comment: Yes, i understand what you are saying, but my question is what are the chances that read call blocks

Comment: It's fairly possible, if your disks are very busy. That's why I recommended you using an io-profiling utility. Also, try `fsync()`ing the file descriptor.

Comment: @cyphar There was a bug in my code after a lot of head banging i could know the problem. Thanks ...